SQL Server Agent log Message [396] An idle CPU condition has not been defined - OnIdle job schedules will have no effect
We are using Sql Server 2022 on Windows Server 2019.
SQL Server Agent service is runing but some scheduled jobs doesnt start at the time.
When I restart SQL Server Agent service, SQL Server Agent log shows [396] An idle CPU condition has not been defined - OnIdle job schedules will have no effect 
warning message.

At the time of a job's schedule again the job didnt start.
Jobs are enabled.
This very strange situation appears today. Yesterday every thing was normal.
I restart the in the order

SQL Server Agent service
SQL Server service
Windows server

problem continues.
We have around 30 jobs scheduled. All jobs has few steps.
Interestingly one job it works every 10 minutes has no problem but others have. For example a job
working every hour doesnt start at the time. I could start manualy.
A 6 year old similar question exist bu situation is different. I can start the service.
How can I solve the problem.

Don't think that log says anything, what about the log in the archieve? Do you see any error related to scheduling? Also, what does that AGENT.OUT file says?

There is no agent log message between 13.07.2024  and 02.08.2024.
Agent.Out file that is located in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log" displays same messages as Sql Management Studio log viewer.

Regarding the 396 message, have you checked SQL Agent > Properties > Advanced to see if "Define idle CPU condition" has been unticked?

Yes, SQL Agent > Properties > Advanced was as a default unticked but after the problem I configured  as 10% and 600 secs. Im attempting to solve the problem. I enabled, disabled the jobs to see the result.

After question I continued to find a solution for the problem.
My attempts to solve the problems are
1.) Create the job again by using right click on job > script job as > create to
2.) Disable, enable job
3.) Configure the Define Idle Cpu condition as follows.
Sql Server Agent>Properties>Advanced>thick Define Idle Cpu condition
4.) Reschedule the job.
This attempt solves the problem.


